# How to import data from Excel 2007 xlsx file into SQL Server 2000 Database?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2000, excel-2007

SQL Server 2000 doesn't seem to support the xml based .xlsx file types.  Besides converting the file to a 97-2003 file type, how else can I achieve this?

Comment: Please use the 'excel-2007' tag rather than 'xlsx'. Watch the suggestion prompts when tagging your questions: any tag with a number less than 10 after it's name is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 2007, you might also have Access 2007.

You can create an Access 2007 Access Data Project (.adp) file.  Connect this to your SQL 2000 database.  Then use the Access 2007 import table function to get the Excel 2007 data.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing [this](http://chikachika.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/import-data-from-excel-2007-to-sql-server-2000/).